# getting the foreign key in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I have the database like

```
 ======= Group ========
 id
 name

 ======= Member ========
 id
 group_id
 firstname
 secondname
 membersince
```

Now in my Group Controller file I have used the action update to update the models

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
  {
    $model=$this->loadModel($id);
    $member = Member::model()->findByPk($_GET['id']);

    if(isset($_POST['Group']))
    {
      $model->attributes=$_POST['Group'];
      if($model->save())
      {
        $member->attributes = $_POST['Member'];
        $member->group_id = $model->id;
        if($member->save())
        {
          $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }
      }
      $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
      'model'=>$model,
      'member'=>$member,
    ));
  }
```

Now as I have two model Group and Member , and in group controller file I am saving member attributes. So my problem is when I am using this line 
 `$member = Member::model()->findByPk($_GET['id']);` 
for getting the group_id from table member where I can get the complete fields for the group. So can some one tell me how o get the group_id from that table.I searched the documntationbut not got any field like findByFk. So pls guide me.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more your question? I still can't understand what you're trying to do and how can I help you.

Comment: Well I want that within group controller  attributes for member should load. I have done the update part but the problem is that how to call group_id from member table where group_id is the foreign key for group table.is there anything in yii like findByFk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `findByAttributes()`

```
$member = Member::model()->findByAttributes(array('group_id'=>$_GET['id']));
```

Answer (score 0):

The relation between is Group and Member is ONE to MANY, so more than one member could exist for a single group id, and your action behavior doesn't look completely correct.

Anyway, the code you are looking for should be the following:

```
$member = Member::model()->findByAttributes(array('group_id', $_GET['id']));
```

It is documented here:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#findByAttributes-detail